# How to parse Json data in javascript containing a url as its name

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing, dbpedia

I am unable to parse the json file obtained from this http://dbpedia.org/data/Los_Angeles.json url.

I need to find the populationTotal, areaTotal, populationDensity fields from the json data obatined from the URL above.

This is a snippet of the json data obtained from http://dbpedia.org/data/Los_Angeles.json url.
Eg.

```
"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/populationTotal" : [ 
{ "type" : "literal",
  "value" : 3792621 , 
  "datatype" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer" } ] ,
"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace/areaTotal" : [ 
{ "type" : "literal", 
  "value" : "1301.9688931491348" , 
  "datatype" : "http://dbpedia.org/datatype/squareKilometre" } ,
```

How could i get this Json data and output it using Javascript.

Comment: `data['http://dbpedia.org/ontology/populationTotal'][0].value`, etc

Comment: @Phil would you be able to give me a code snippet? That line is not working

Comment: @tanvioka I've put a tested answer that demonstrates how to do it.  Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do this help you?

```
var populationTotalData=[];
for(var key in data) {
    if(key.match(/populationTotal/))
    // or simplier: if(key.indexOf("populationTotal")>-1)
        populationTotalData.push(data[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), you often can't directly fetch the data using JavaScript.  However, it turns out that dbpedia.org supports JSON-P, so you can get the data with straight JavaScript like this:

```
// This is the "callback" function. The 'data' variable will contain the JSON.
// You can access it like I have done in the alert below.
mycallback = function(data){
    alert(data["http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Los_Angeles"]["http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs"][0].value);
};

// This is the function we use to fetch the JSON data:
function requestServerCall(url) {
    var head = document.head;
    var script = document.createElement("script");

    script.setAttribute("src", url);
    head.appendChild(script);
    head.removeChild(script);
}

// Note the query string that I have added (?callback=mycallback).
// This is the name of the function that will be called with the JSON data.
requestServerCall('http://dbpedia.org/data/Los_Angeles.json?callback=mycallback');
```

A lot more really excellent information on JSONP can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about).  You could loop inside of the `mycallback` function using some code like this.  Obviously, you'd have to make nested loops to get exactly what you want, so this code would need modifying to fit your exact needs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  for(var index in data) { 
    console.log(data[index]); 
  }
</script>
```

The other method would be via PHP.  For example: you could pitch the whole page into a JavaScript variable like this:

```
<?php
  $los_angeles = file_get_contents('http://dbpedia.org/data/Los_Angeles.json');
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = <?php echo $los_angeles; ?>;
  alert(data["http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Los_Angeles"]["http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs"][0].value)
</script>
```